# jQuery Mobile - Remove back button only when pointing to a particular page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile web app with a login screen. After logging in, the user goes to the homescreen of the app. Since I have back buttons enabled for the entire application, the back button appears on the homescreen; however, pressing "Back" now will take the user back to the login page (which I don't want). At the same time, the homescreen should have a "Back" button, since  user might get to the homescreen from some other screen in the app and might want to go back.

So basically is there any easy way to disable the back button if it's going to go to the login screen, but not if it's going someplace else?

Comment: I think it's a better approach to automatically redirect the user to home/default page if he's already logged in

Comment: I'm already doing that. But it's better to not let the user have the option of going back to the login if he's going to get redirected anyway. Saves time, requests etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about setting up an array of pages visited and checking it to see if the last page was the login page:

```
//setup array of page views
var page_views = [];
//add event handler for `pageshow` event
$('[data-role="page"]').live('pageshow', function () {
    //add current page to page_views array
    page_views.push(this.id);
    var page_views_length = page_views.length;
    //check if the current page is the homescreen and if the last page was the login page
    if (this.id == 'homescreen_id' && page_views_length > 1 && page_views[(page_views_length - 2)] == 'login_id') {//this assumes your login page has the id of `login_id` and your homescreen page has the id of `homescreen_id`
        //run code to hide the back button
    }
});
```

Comment: Did this, except that i'm only storing the last page, instead of an array with the page history. Only the previous page matters

Answer (score 0):

Another strategy you could consider is having the login page add a parameter to the query string of the home page indicating that back should be disabled.

```
http://myapp.com/page.html?backDisable=true
```

Inside your page a simple javascript call could determine if the parameter was passed and if so disable the back button.  Here's a sample using the [URL parser plugin](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser).

```
if ($.url().param('backDisable') === 'true') {
  $('#backButton')[0].disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: jQuery Mobile also has some methods for parsing URLs (like `$.mobile.path.parseUrl`): http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/api/methods.html

Answer (score 0):

Add data-ajax="false" to your login-in form.
I assume your login form and home screen exist on the same domain.

So when you go to example.com you see login form (if not logged in)
... when you go to example.com you see a welcome screen...

PHP example of my index layout... (dirty):

```
<div data-role="page">
<?php if ($notloggedin) { ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?= $this->baseUrl('/'); ?>" id="login-form" data-ajax="false">...form...</form>
<?php } else { ?>
    YOUR PAGE
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

[jquery mobile page links](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-links.html)